# Show the quotient by equivalence $A \sim B \iff A^2+23A=B^2+23B$ is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, matrices, quotient-spaces

So, in the set $T$ of 2x2 uppertriangular matrices one has defined
$$
A \sim B \iff A^2+23A=B^2+23B
$$

Is the quotient $\quad T/\sim \quad$ Hausdorff?

**My attempt**

- I've shown that every small enough neighbourhood of the matrix $A^2+23A$ is non-empty.
- Then I said that small enough neighbourhoods of two distinct matrices $A^2+23A$ and $B^2+23B$ does not intersect(I used that as an obvious fact)

So, from the last step I concluded the quotient space is Hausdorff.

Am I right? Other ideas?

Comment: You can probably save some calculational complexity by completing the squares and rewriting the condition to $(A+\frac{23}2I)^2 = (B+\frac{23}2I)^2$. Then translate all of $T$ by $\frac{23}2I$ and see that the quotient you're after must be homeomorphic to the one by $A^2=B^2$.

Comment: @Troposphere Nice trick:) does make sense. So, the hausdorffness of quotient by relation $A^2+23A=B^2+23B$ is equivalent to the hausdorffness of quotient by $A^2=B^2$?

Comment: That was indeed my point. However, on a bit further thought that is actually a detour anyway. All you need to know, really, is that the map $X\mapsto X^2+23X$ is _continuous_ into a Hausdorff space; the details of it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Troposphere can you please explain a little bit more your last idea(about the map continuity). Does there exist some sort of theorem I can refer to?

Comment: I mean, does the continuosness of the projection map $f: T->T/\sim$ on Hausdorff $T$ implies that $T/\sim$ is also Hausdorff? ($f$ is surjective also!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've shown that every small enough neighbourhood of the matrix $A^2+23A$ is non-empty.

This is true, but something of a tautology. A neighborhood of a point (it doesn't need to be "small enough") is *always* non-empty because by definition it contains the point itself!

> Then I said that small enough neighbourhoods of two distinct matrices $A^2+23A$ and $B^2+23B$ does not intersect(I used that as an obvious fact)

What you need to make this statement less handwavy is the knowledge that $T$ *itself* (in its role as the space where $A^2+23A$ and $B^2+23B$ live) is Hausdorff.

The general principle at work is: If you have topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ and a continuous function $f: X\to Y$ you can form the quotient $X/{\sim_f}$ where $x_1\sim_f x_2$ iff $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. This quotient is in bijective correspondence with $f(X)\subseteq Y$.

Furthermore the topology of $X/{\sim_f}$ is at least as fine as the subspace topology on $f(X)$ -- since preimages of open sets in $Y$ under the continuous map $f$ are open in $X$.

Now if $Y$ is Hausdorff, then every subspace of it is Hausdorff too, and therefore $X/{\sim}_f$ is Hausdorff because making a topology finer will not harm the Hausdorff property.

Comment: great answer, thanks!